# Disable SSL in PHP imagepng

Tags: php, image, ssl, image-processing

I am getting an SSL error when I try to call `imagepng` in PHP.

`Message: imagecreatefrompng(): SSL operation failed with code 1`

I know there is a way to disable SSL verification when using `get_put_contents()` but can you do this with `imagepng`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you should be able to combine `file_get_contents` with `imagecreatefromstring`, e.g.

```
$context = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
];

$url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo242.png';
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($context));

$img = imagecreatefromstring($response);
```